# How to fix transitive dependency generated by dependabot

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

We have enabled dependabot alert on our repository. But dependabot is not opening new PR for some of vulnerabilities.
For example :

Below is one of alert I see
`
The latest possible version that can be installed is 2.4.2 because of the following conflicting dependencies:

zip-folder@1.0.0 requires lodash@~2.4.1 via archiver@0.11.0
zip-folder@1.0.0 requires lodash@~2.4.1 via a transitive dependency on zip-stream@0.4.1
The earliest fixed version is 4.17.21.
`

But Zip-folder is not updated on npm repo so far as fix on lodash was released 9 year ago i.e;v 1.1.1  but loadash latest version 4.17.21 and it's using v 1.1.0

As zip dependency is transitive should I update v1.1.1 in my package.json manually. Will it override the version used by zip or there is some alternative of this approach?